# c# comboxBox add default non selected text

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, windows-forms-designer

I have a combobox and I fill it like this:

```
private void fillFarmAreaData()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
    dt.Columns.Add("Description", typeof(string));
    farmArea.ValueMember = "ID";
    farmArea.DisplayMember = "Description";
    farmArea.SelectedValue = "ID";
    for (int i = 0; i < StaticData.FarmAreaNames.Count; i++) {
        dt.Rows.Add(StaticData.FarmAreaValues[i], StaticData.FarmAreaNames[i]);
    }
    farmArea.DataSource = dt;
}
```

where StaticData class is this:

```
static class  StaticData
{
    public static List<string> FarmAreaNames = new List<string>() { .... strings here};
    public static List<string> FarmAreaValues = new List<string>() { "1", "10", "11", "12", "13" };

}
```

The problem is that when I run the form, I already get the first value selected. what I want is to make the first option as this `Select Area Name`

#### What I have tried

I added `Selected Area Name` as the first string in the `FarmAreaNames` and added `-1` as the first `FarmAreaValue`

and then when the user click save, I check the value, if it is `-1` I show a validation error message.

However,  I would like to know if windows form provides a better way for that.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this after adding the data source for the Combobox control and finally insert an item to the specific position.

use

> comboBox1.Items.Insert(0, "Select Area Name");

Comment: This is the way that I am doing now